# Convert date from MMM DD, YYYY to mm/dd/yy

Tags: c#, date

i got date in my db in the form of MMM DD,YYYY

```
String thisDate1 = "Jan 05, 2009";
```

in order to get arithmetic operations such as add days i have to change it to standard format i.e mm/dd/yy. how can i do this. please help

Comment: Just never store dates in a string, use DateTime instead.  Where it is unambiguous, culture independent, compact and fast.  It shouldn't be turned into a string until the last possible moment, just before you show it to a human.

Answer (score 5):

Your string is fine as-is, you can use DateTime.Parse to convert it to a DateTime object which you can do your arithmetic on, like so:

```
var thisDate = DateTime.Parse(thisDate1);
var nextDate = thisDate.AddDays(1);
var nextDateAsString = nextDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

Also be careful with your casing, your current string is actually in **MMM dd, yyyy** format. **DD** would actually give you the letters **DD** themselves, as would **YYYY**. **mm** is minutes, while **MM** is for months. You can find more details on this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

Also, as @HansPassant pointed out, you don't want to be storing your dates in a string until the last possible moment.